# Cannot run my go program as a service on Windows server 2019

Tags: windows, go, service

I want to run a REST API written in Go as a Windows service, but when I try to start the service I get an error.

This is how I install the service with Powershell:

```
$params = @{
  Name = "AHS"
  BinaryPathName = '"C:\Temp\ah.exe --service"'
  DisplayName = "AH Service"
  StartupType = "Manual"
  Description = "This is a test service."
}
New-Service @params
```

This is how I start the service:

```
Start-Service "AHS"
```

This is the error I get:

```
 At C:\Windows\Temp\script-62cfbba7-a4ef-b024-51ce-ba0b6804cbd7.ps1:10 char:1
 + Start-Service "AHS"
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service],
    ServiceCommandException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

This is a simplified version of the code just to sort out running it as a service:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/kardianos/service"
)

const serviceName = "AHS"


type program struct{}

func (p program) Start(s service.Service) error {
    fmt.Println(s.String() + " started")
    go p.run()
    return nil
}

func (p program) Stop(s service.Service) error {
    fmt.Println(s.String() + " stopped")
    return nil
}

func (p program) run() {

    str := "hello, world \n"
    fileName := "log.txt"

    for {
        err := writeToFile(str, fileName)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {
    serviceConfig := &service.Config{
        Name:        serviceName,
    }
    prg := &program{}
    s, err := service.New(prg, serviceConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot create the service: " + err.Error())
    }
    err = s.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Cannot start the service: " + err.Error())
    }
}

func writeToFile(str string, fileName string) error {
    file, err := os.Create(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        if !os.IsExist(err) {
            return err
        }
    }
    defer file.Close()
    _, err = file.WriteString(str)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Are you running [`Start-Service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-service?view=powershell-7.2#notes) in an elevated PowerShell session? (right click 'PowerShell' click 'Run As Administrator'). [This issue](https://github.com/kardianos/service/pull/314) may also be relevant.

Comment: I'm doing it with Packer, but good point. I'll double check.

Comment: Just tried it, didn't help.

Comment: Works for me if I change `BinaryPathName = '"C:\Temp\ah.exe --service"'` to `BinaryPathName = "C:\Temp\ah.exe"` (and, obviously, use a path that exists on my machine). Check in Event Viewer for specific errors (should be in the System log).

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem.